# Is accessing a local variable is much more efficient than accessing a field in ART?

Tags: java, android, android-runtime

I've read this [here](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex2.html):

> Accessing a local variable is much more efficient than accessing a field in the Dalvik VM

And Android has used ART [since the 4.4 release.](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/art.html)

Is accessing a local variable since 4.4 much more efficient than accessing a field in ART?

Comment: The original phrase in your link is referring to Dalvik: `Accessing a local variable is much more efficient than accessing a field in the Dalvik VM` no9t ART though.